# C# - String that contains varying digits

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a method that checks to see if a string (lets say "strparent") contains another string ("strsub") but the thing is, "strsub" does not always contain the same value as there is a digit within it that can be any whole digit.

Example 1:

" tab (ver 3) by "

Example 2:

" tab (ver 12) by "

I'm not too experienced with regular expressions so I'm not sure if this could be easily done with them or not.

Comment: If you can make `strsub` equal to `" tab \(ver \d+\) by "` then you can use a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex would be simple (untested): `@" tab \(ver \d+\) by ";`

This is a handy [regular expression tester](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) for C#:

Comment: `(` is a special char in regexes

Comment: need to escape ( and ) with \

Comment: Ah, the \ is a special character on SO as well O_o.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

```
\(substr \d+\)
```

Use this regex

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly easy. I would just tell you but regular expressions are probably something you should familiarize yourself with and this would be a good first attempt as the expression would not be very complex.

Some REGEX resources:

http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx

Comment: I've experimented a little bit with Regular Expressions, mainly in PHP, but still not enough to do it off the top of my head.  I'll look into it more. +1

Comment: Cool. Bear in mind too that Microsoft realm regular expressions and Linux realm regular expressions have some slight differences. :)